# How to do unit test to check input is not null in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest, assertion

This is my first time trying to write a unit test in Python. I have a simple function like this:

```py
def sum_num(a, b):
  return a+b
```

I want to do unit test to check that the input (a, b) is not null and output is not null.

```py
import unittest

class SumTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sum_output_not_null(self):
        self.assertTrue(add_num(3,4))

    def test_sum_input_not_null(self):
        # How to check input (a and b) is not None ?
        self.assertIsNotNone(a)
...

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SumTest)
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
runner.run(suite)
```

I am getting errors in the unit test run..

```py
test_sum_input_not_null (__main__.SumTest) ... ERROR
test_sum_output_not_null (__main__.SumTest) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: test_sum_input_not_null (__main__.SumTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<command-1933936>", line 7, in test_sum_input_not_null
    self.assertIsNotNone(a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
Out[4]: <unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=2 errors=1 failures=0>
```

How do I check a and b are not null? Also probably want to check both a and b are integers as well. I read somewhere about setup(). Do I need to do that to test inputs for a function?

Comment: you got the error because a was never defined..

Comment: I kind of know that. I am not sure how to define that and where to define that or how to pass it into the unit test.

Comment: your unit test need to check the RESULT of a function/method call. You can add a check for empty arguments in the crucial function's body. Then, your test can invoke the function with different args

Comment: unit testing basically entails testing for arbitrary inputs, where the expected outputs are known. So one would expect certain fixed inputs for a series of predefined unittest where you assert against the expected output. So in this case you would do some `asserts` statement with the inputs (None, None) as one of your examples to see what they return

Comment: @BlueRineS I just started trying out unit testing in python...I am not sure how is it different from doing regular checks in the function like you mentioned. If so, why do we still need unit test?

Comment: Unit tests are to ensure that your code isn't broken. You can't use them to _fix_ the code, yet you can use them to _test_ code. I think that is an important seperation you need to keep..

Answer (score 4):

> I want to do unit test to check that the input (a, b) is not null and output is not null.

Either you don't understand yet the purpose of testing or you're asking some TDD related question.

You don't test quoted, you test does your function deal well when such a condition occurs.

So, you should create test function(s) and make a call inside it like:

```
def test_when_a_is_null(self):
    self.assertIsNotNone(add_num(None, 5))
```

and the similar when b is None and when both are None.

But, that means your function should deal with the conditions:

```
def add_num(a, b):
    if a is not None and b is not None:
        return a + b
    elif a is not None:
        return a
    elif b is not None:
        return b
    return 0
```

Comment: `if a is not None and b is not None` can be simplified to `if not a and not b` as far as I know

Comment: Nope, try with (None, False).

Comment: Absolutely, that's the intention, it should work as none of those two arguments is None. The question is about value being null (and None is counterpart in Python for that), so the answer deals with that. Btw, 1+False equals 1.

Comment: Yeah I know. that's why I edited my comment (after my realization) to include that it actually works when you add them XD